# kubernetes: intra-cluster isolation of applications

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I have been experimenting with `k8s`/`kops`/`aws` suite.

So far things have been going pretty well (except an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/4250) when updating cluster via `kops`)

I want to be able to make use of my existing resources/cluster and deploy 2 flavors of my app (i.e. `production` and `testing`) in the same cluster.

I would like to be on the safe side and maximize as much as possible the isolation between the `k8s` resources of those two deployments.

Definately there going on different namespaces.

From some investigation I have found out that I need to also apply `NetworkPolicy` to prevent inter-`namespace` communication; however applying `NetworkPolicy` resources requires a supporting networking solution (currently using `kubenet`, the default of `kops` which **doesn't**).

What is the solution/plugin to go for?

Just want (at least for the time being) the level of isolation described above which I assume can be achieved via `NetworkPolicy` even if there is a common `CIDR` for all pods (just saying that to emphasise that there is a need for just the simplest possible networking solution that achieves that, nothing more fancy with multiple `CIDRs` etc).

Ideally I would like to be able **just** to use `NetworkPolicy` resource for some `namespace`-based (`namespaceSelector`) and `pod`-based (`podSelector`) ingress rules and that's it (?)

Answer (score 1):

On my kops clusters I use [weave](https://www.weave.works/oss/net/) networking (also I provision them as private topology, which excludes `kubenet` anyway). So my first suggestion would be to go with a different networking, weave and calico being first ones coming to my mind.

Other then that, you might want to look into service mesh solution like Istio which can leverage NetworkPolicies as well (some [istio policy reading](https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-using-network-policy.html))

Comment: I also assume you use bastion for ssh-ing into your cluster since you are on a private topology?

Comment: indeed bastion it is

Comment: pls allow me an additional question: `weave` is used just to support the enforcement of `NetworkPolicy`? is it considered a bad practice if I spin up my cluster with `weave` **just** to be able to enforce `NetworkPolicy` ? (I am asking cause I assume any network solution is meant to to much more things than just enabling `NetworkPolicy`, right?)

Comment: all my cross-pod communication goes via weave, NetworkPolicy support is sort of a side effect for me. Private topology enforces use of a different networking solution then kubenet so I had to choose anyway. And in other setups I use weaves ability to established an encrypted peer channels over public network (no use for it in pure kops/aws, but I have some hybrid)